# Prove that $\mathbb F_8=\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X+1)$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I'm new to field extensions and I can neither see why or how to prove this statement.

If I'm not mistaken, to construct a splitting field, you construct rupture fields one after the other, using that *the $8$ element field is the splitting field of $X^8-X$ over $\mathbb F_2$*, since $2$ is the only prime divisor of 8.

Over $\mathbb F_2$ $X^8-X$ has two roots : $0$ and $1$. Therefore $X^8-X=X(X-1)(1+X+...+X^6)$. The last factor, call it $P$, has no roots. So let $\alpha$ be a root in some extension $\mathbb F_2(\alpha)$ of $\mathbb F_2$.

We now have $P=(X-\alpha)(X^5+\alpha X^4+...+\alpha^4X+\alpha^5)$.

I suspect $\alpha$ might not be the way to go and if so, my second plan would be to reduce $P$. I don't know how to do this but assuming it to be done, hence having $P=P_1...P_n$, I could start using $P_1$'s rupture field, and then my best guess is that if $\mathbb F_2[X]/(P_1)$ is not sufficient, I re-reduce $P$ over this new field and consider the rupture field of one of the factors, and so on.

Now assuming I wasn't given the statement itself, is it elementary to construct the $8$ element field using $\mathbb F_2$ ?

Comment: Why do you want to construct a splitting field? The problem (which you only stated in the title of the question: please do not do that...) has not much to do with that.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that $X^3+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout - If I'm not mistaken that would prove that $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X+1)$ is a field, and contains at least one extra root of $P$, but I don't know how to find out whether it has more.

Comment: Again: Why are you looking for a splitting field of the polynomial? That is not what you want.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - I am looking for the splitting field of $X^8-X$ by virtue of the theorem I adapted for this particular case. This polynomial partially splits over $\mathbb F_2$ so I'm seeking to split the remaining factor.

Comment: Why are you doing that? If you want to do is to prove the statement that appears in the title of your question, then that but is completely irrelevant. But oh well, I'll leave you to find all the splitting fields you want.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't really see what I'm doing wrong, I think that I'm supposed to use the theorem about $X^8-X$ to find $\mathbb F_8$, and then prove that it is in fact the rupture field of $X^3+X+1$, is there another way to do this ?

Comment: (rupture field -> splitting field)

Comment: But **why** do you want to find the splitting field of $x^3+x+1$?! (Notice that I asked you this in my very first comment above, and you still have not answered. I guess I'll just leave it for others to try to understand what you are doing.)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Have I said anywhere that I wanted to find the splitting field of $X^3+X+1$ ? If so please point it out so I can change that. I want its rupture field, more precisely I want to prove that its rupture field is $\mathbb F_8$. As a matter of fact, the rupture field of this specific polynomial happens to be its splitting field as I know from the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the polynomial is irreducible over the field $F_2$. From that it will follow that the corresponding quotient ring is indeed a field.

Compute its dimension over $F_2$ and using that you will immediately know how many elements it has: eight.

Now, to show that it is isomorphic to $F_8$ what you do depends on what you know about this last field. For example, you might know that it is the unique field with eight elements up  to isomorphism, and then of course you are done.

Comment: All that makes sense to me, so that proves that it is the splitting field. Is this something I would be expected to work out if I wasn't given the statement in the first place ?

Comment: It is very basic. I'd say that if you are supposed to be able to deal with fields at all you should be used to do this sort of thing.

Comment: You insist with the splitting field! No, all that does not proved that nothing is the splitting field of anything, really.

Answer (score 0):

In characteristic $2$
$$X^8-X=X(X-1)(X^3+X+1)(X^3+X^2+1).$$
If $\alpha$ is a zero of $X^3+X+1$ then
$$X^3+X+1=(X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^2)(X-\alpha^4)$$
and
$$X^3+X^2+1=(X-\alpha^3)(X-\alpha^5)(X-\alpha^6).$$
This implies that
$$\Bbb F_8=\Bbb F_2(\alpha)\cong\frac{\Bbb F_2[X]}{\left<X^3+X+1\right>}.$$

Comment: This approach can only come to mind if you already know it ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to reduce $X^8-X$ the way you did without knowing that $X^3+X+1$ is involved, so as to construct the $8$ element field from scratch ?